# $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^ka^n=0$ for $a\in (0,1)$ and $k$ a positive integer

Tags: limits

Let $a\in (0,1)$ and $k$ a positive integer. Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^ka^n=0.$$

I know how the case $k=1$ can be solved (Let $a=\frac{1}{b+1}$ with $b>0$ and then by the expansion of the binomial we have $(\frac1a)^n> {n \choose 2}b^2$. It follows that $0<na^n<\frac{2}{(n-1)b^2}$, and since the right hand side is a sequence that converges to $0$, the conclusion follows).

However, I can't figure out the case where $k>2$. The author of the book I took this exercise from suggests the same exact method (observe that $(\frac 1a)^n>{n \choose k+1}b^{k+1}$ and then $n^ka^n<\frac{n^k}{{n \choose k+1}b^{k+1}}$. Then we need to prove that the sequence $\frac{n^k}{{n \choose k+1}b^{k+1}}$ tends to $0$. Can we do this by basic properties of limits or by the definition? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using l-hospitals rule followed by induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applying the case you proved $(k=1)$ for $c:=a^{1/k} \in (0,1)$ would give that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot c^n =0$$
then $$n^k \cdot a^n=(n \cdot c^n)^k \underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
since, for a fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$,  $x\mapsto x^k$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

As hinted, write $a = \frac{1}{1 + q}$ where $q > 0$, therefore
\begin{align*}
(1 + q)^n & = 1 + nq + \cdots + \binom{n}{k + 1}q^{k + 1} + \cdots + q^n \\
          & > \frac{n!}{(k + 1)!(n - k - 1)!}q^{k + 1} \\
          & = \frac{1}{(k + 1)!}n(n - 1)(n - 2)\cdots(n - k) q^{k + 1},
\end{align*}
whence (pairing $n$ with $n - i, i = 1, \ldots, k$, and you still get one extra term $\frac{1}{n}$ left):
\begin{align*}
0 < \frac{n^k}{(1 + q)^n} & < \frac{(k + 1)!}{q^{k + 1}}
\frac{\underbrace{n \times n \times \cdots \times n}_{k \text{ terms }}}{\underbrace{n(n - 1)(n - 2)\cdots(n - k)}_{(k + 1) \text{ terms }}} \\
& = \frac{(k + 1)!}{q^{k + 1}}\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \times 
\cdots \times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{k}{n}} \to 0.
\end{align*}
Now the result follows from the squeeze principle.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question... but why is the last line of the proof true? (Why $\frac{1}{1-\frac{j}{n}}$ tends to $0$)? I am a very beginner to limits.

Comment: $1 - \frac{i}{n} \to 1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, k$. Note $k$ is a fixed number.

Comment: I still don't get it. We have that $\frac{1}{1-\frac{j}{n}}=\frac{n}{n-j}$, so the limit of this is 0 if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $n_0$ such that $|\frac{n}{n-j}|<\epsilon$, for all $n\ge n_0$. But for $n\ge \max{n_0,j}$ we get that $1<|\frac{n}{n-j}|<\epsilon$ which implies $\epsilon>1$. This clearly is a contradiction since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily choosen.

Comment: Do you know the simple algebraic rule of limit operations: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{a}{b}$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = b \neq 0$? Take $a_n \equiv 1$ and $b_n = 1 - \frac{i}{n}$ here.

Comment: Nope. I'm not that far in the book. I don't know any operations with limits yet. This exercise was right after the squeeze principle, which is before operations with limits in the book.

Comment: In my opinion, arithmetic rules like that should be taught immediately after the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition. In fact, the answer you accepted also implicitly used the rule $\lim(a_nb_n) = \lim(a_n)\lim(b_n)$. They are not profound (but very important) at all and easy to prove. For a reference, see Theorem 3.3 of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin.

Comment: Shouldn't you right after the first inequality have the fraction $\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}$? I think you wrote $k!$ after that, instead of $(k+1)!$. Also, $q$ should have exponent $k+1$ on the last line.

Comment: @Bman72 Thank you.  These are indeed typos, and I have corrected all of them.

Comment: @Zhanxiong thank you for the nice solution